# Apple keyboard mapping on Ubuntu KDE

Tags: keyboard, xorg, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I want to configure the Apple keyboard mapping on dell precision notebook keyboard on Ubuntu KDE such that alt-> win, ctrl->alt, fn -> ctrl.
That means i want to make the dell precision notebook keyboard to feel more like apple keyboard.

I tried to configure in the keyboard settings but this didn't work properly, i.e. the mappings didn't work for some hotkeys like ctrl+c. Is there any way that the modified mapping really works well in all applications?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling the below procedures are said to solve your issue.

> Add apple:badmap option to the "XkbOptions" in the "InputDevice"
>   section in your xorg.conf. The section should look like this:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Generic Keyboard"
    Driver "kbd"
    Option "CoreKeyboard"
    Option "XkbRules" "xorg"
    Option "XkbModel" "apple"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    Option "XkbVariant" ",winkeys"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:shift_caps_toggle,apple:badmap"
EndSection
```

> This should swap problematic keys under X. If it doesn't help one can
>   try adding apple:goodmap instead.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mactel-support/+bug/214786)

Comment: This was not exactly what i meant. i got dellprecision notebook keyboard. i edited my question to make it clearer.